# Adding multiple handles in Ember nouislider

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to add 2 handles in ember nouislider but can't seem to figure out to,i've tried using the array but when i do that the slider doensn't even show up and also tried putting 2 starting points but didn't work.

```
{{range-slider
           start=[1,500]
           min=data.filterData.filterRange.min
           max=data.filterData.filterRange.max
           on-change="sliderChanged"
         }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start=[1,500]` - this will produce parse error. Define property `startRange:[1,500]` and use it.

```
{{range-slider
           start=startRange ...}}
```

Not sure this will fix your original issue.